# Use size in Python

Tags: python, function, numpy, methods, size

I created a ndarray array in python

```
temp = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

To measure the length of this array, I can use

```
temp.size
```

or

```
np.size(temp)
```

both return 4. But I'm wondering what's the difference between the two expressions? Also, to get the lena image, I need to write

```
>>> import scipy.misc
>>> lena = scipy.misc.lena()
```

I'm wondering why there's a bracket pair after lena? Isn't lena a matrix? Something with () is like a function. I understand lena() is a function takes no inputs and returns a ndarray. I just feel like it's tedious to write this way.

In Matlab, it's quite clear to distinguish between a constant and a function. Function is defined and called with (), but constant (or pre-stored) can be called directly, e.g., "blobs.png"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.size(temp)` is a little more general than `temp.size`. At first glance, they appear to do the same thing:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> x.size
6
>>> np.size(x)
6
```

This is true when you don't supply any additional arguments to `np.size`. But if you look at the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.size.html#numpy.ma.size) for `np.size`, you'll see that it accepts an additional `axis` parameter, which gives the size along the corresponding axis:

```
>>> np.size(x, 0)
2
>>> np.size(x, 1)
3
```

As far as your second question, `scipy.misc.lena` *is* a function as you point out. It is not a matrix. It is a function returning a matrix. The function (presumably) loads the data on the fly so that it isn't placed in memory whenever you import the `scipy.misc` module. This is a *good* thing, and actually not all that different than matlab.

Comment: I guess you mean `size` instead of `shape`, right? The `shape` in your example would actually be `(2, 3)`.

Comment: @Matthias Oops! Good catch. Fixed!

Answer (score 2):

`temp.size` is a property [numpy.ndarray.size](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html) of `ndarray` where as [numpy.size](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.size.html#numpy.ma.size) is a free function which calls the size property of `ndarray` or any other similar object which has the `size` method.

The reason `numpy.size` is flexible because it can act upon `ndarray` like object or objects that can be converted to `ndarray`

`numpy.size` also excepts an optional `axis`, along which it would calculate the size.

Here is the [implementation](http://nullege.com/codes/search/numpy.size?fulldoc=1) of numpy.array.

```
def size(a, axis=None):
    if axis is None:
        try:
            return a.size
        except AttributeError:
            return asarray(a).size
    else:
        try:
            return a.shape[axis]
        except AttributeError:
            return asarray(a).shape[axis]
```